# Implement internet gateway in android

Tags: java, android, networking, mesh

For my research I need to implement an internet gateway in Android. similarly to what Open Garden does to make android utilize facility provided by its own to use its provided stream etc *as* an internet connection. This app does not require any  root access.

So my question is very narrow: how to create such a facility. and how to instruct Android to use it instead of an already existent LTE connection for example. I am not asking about protocols etc. just how to integrate something like that into the android without the use of root access; what APIs etc.

Comment: lets say I am working on a routing protocol; how do I implement an access point for Android for its internal use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well; after some short research the actual solution is to implement a VpnService; make localhost the server and from there route your pakcets anywhere you wish:) there seems to be trouble bugs not fixed yet (people actually waiting for yeara for google to fix) in cases like when other apps do not handle detect the vpn connection properly. Anyway:) here's the answer. I'll be on my way now.